# How to get the verify in selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, element

I am writing a test for cancel a data request at the page: `https://school.moodledemo.net/admin/tool/dataprivacy/mydatarequests.php`

There is a pop-up when cancel a data request[image]

My code to catch this:

```
    def cancelRequest(self):
        toggle_button = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "action-menu-toggle-1")
        toggle_button.click()
        cancel_button = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "actionmenuaction-1")
        cancel_button.click()
        try:
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            self.driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Cancel request").click()
        except:
            print("nothing")
```

But I cannot choose the cancel request button. It always prints nothing. Can anybody help me? Thanks

Comment: Is it an alert? Please check the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this an alert pop up message, it is recommended to employ the 'alert' method for its implementation.

```
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
```

If you wish to proceed with accepting the pop-up message, kindly write this after switching to alert.

```
alert.accept()
```

Conversely, should you choose to decline the message,
You can provide this

```
alert.dismiss()
```

Comment: If you would like to conduct a hands-on test on using alerts, I have created a test case using Test Assist, a no-code Selenium editor. Feel free to review and execute the test case by clicking on the following link:  https://app.testassist.dev/program/e4f82912-8273-4f4a-a5cd-3a009521a76f